# Plotting angle vs radius in polar coordinates in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, polar-coordinates

I have a dataset with radius values under X column and angle values  in multiple Y columns.

```
Radius (X)  Angle1(Y1)  Angle2(Y2)  Angle3(Y3)
281         55.4        91.2        93.0
282         63.5        92.4        86.0
283         67.7        95.7        90.5
284         62.9        93.9        92.8
285         63.8        100.2       91.5
286         64.7        91.8        85.3
287         69.3        93.1        89.2
288         68.2        97.2        85.5
```

However, gnuplot polar mode treats angle as X and radius as Y.

Is there any way to invert this behaviour to plot the dataset (and optionally smooth the data)? Or any better-suited linux software for the task?

Comment: Indeed. Specify the respective columns in your plot command: `set polar; plot "file" using 2:1`

Comment: @Christoph, thank you for your attempt, but pointing out basic commands is pretty useless.  Iknow the basics of plotting and can read a manual.  I was asking if there is way that does not require putting the horse before the cart each and every time.

Comment: You asked how to exchange interpretation of angle and radius and I told you how to do that. That the way is simple but doesn't match your expectation doesn't make it wrong. If you want a different _default_  behaviour should have asked more precisely. In any case, since you haven't shown any line of gnuplot code, guessing is all what remains. Good luck